# How to sort Angular material table based on button click

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to sort mat table when I click buttons.

Mat table has sort functionalities when you click the column name it sorts the table based on the column.

I want to sort the table based on price when I click the button "low to high"
Here is my code:
shopping component
`

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IItem } from '../items';
import {MatSort, Sort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import { LoginComponent } from '../login/login.component';
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { AddItemComponent } from '../add-item/add-item.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-shopping',
  templateUrl: './shopping.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shopping.component.scss']
})
export class ShoppingComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit{

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private sharedService: SharedService,
    private dialog: MatDialog) {}

  @Input() loginSuccess!: EventEmitter<string>;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(LoginComponent) loginComponent!: LoginComponent;
  @ViewChild('empTbSort') empTbSort = new MatSort();

  private url = 'assets/items.json';
  username!: any;
  data!: any;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'quantity', 'price', 'count', 'add'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<IItem>(this.data);
  labelCount = 0
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get(this.url)
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.data = response;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
    })

    this.username = this.sharedService.username
  } 

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.priceHighToLow();
  }

  openCart() {}

  updateItems(row: any) {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.data.length; ++i) {
      if(this.data[i]["add"] == row.add) {
        this.data[i]["count"] -= 1;
        this.labelCount += 1
      }
    }
    this.dialog.open(AddItemComponent, {width: "20%"})
  }

  priceHighToLow() {}
}
```

`shopping html`

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <button mat-icon-button>
        <mat-icon>polymer</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <span>Welcome <b>{{username}}</b></span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="openCart()">
        <mat-icon [matBadge]="labelCount" matBadgeColor="warn">add_shopping_cart</mat-icon>
    </button>
</mat-toolbar>
<div class="container">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.id }}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Product Name</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.name }}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="quantity">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Quantity</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.quantity }}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Price</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.price | currency }}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="count">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Count</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.count }}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="add">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Action</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
                <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="updateItems(item)">Add item</button>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<table> 
    <h2>Price</h2>
    <button (click)="priceHighToLow()"> High to low</button><br>
    <!-- <button (click)="priceLowToHigh()"> High to low</button>
    <h2>Quantity</h2>
    <button (click)="quantityHighToLow()"> High to low</button><br>
    <button (click)="quantityLowToHigh()"> High to low</button> -->
</table>
```

`
Once I click the High to low button I want the table to be sorted based on the price.
I want to sort the price from low to high as well.

I need a way to custom sort mat table based on button clicks.

Comment: Hello! Have you considered the following material table sort example? https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview

Comment: @JoosepParts Yes, It sorts based on click, once I click the column name, it sorts the column to ascending order, if I click again it sorts the column to descending order, but I want to sort column, both ascending and descending order on two separate button clicks, I'm learning angular for the past 2 weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Component.html

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="sortDataSource('price', 'asc')">ASC</button>
<button mat-raised-button
          (click)="sortDataSource('price', 'desc')">DESC</button>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort
                       #empTbSort="matSort" class="mat-elevation-z8">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>ID</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.id }}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Product Name</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.name }}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="quantity">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Quantity</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.quantity }}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Price</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.price | currency }}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="count">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Count</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.count }}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="add">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Action</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
                    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="updateItems(item)">Add item</button>
                </td>
            </ng-container>
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
```

### Component.ts

```
@ViewChild('empTbSort') empTbSort = new MatSort();

ngAfterViewInit() {

this.dataSource.sort = this.empTbSort;
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get(this.url)
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.data = response;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
      this.dataSource.sort = this.empTbSort;
    })

    this.username = this.sharedService.username
  }
```

Description of changes as below for sort column using table header:

- add code as mention to table tag - `matSort #empTbSort="matSort"`
- add `mat-sort-header` to `mat-header-cell`
- changes to component using ref variable of type `MatSort()` using this reference give control of sorting.

### Approach of button click

```
 sortDataSource(id: string, start: string) {
    this.dataSource.data.sort((a, b) => {
      return start === 'asc'
        ? a[id] - b[id]
        : start === 'desc'
        ? b[id] - a[id]
        : a[id] - b[id];
    });
    this.dataSource._updateChangeSubscription();
  }
```

Description Add two button for manually apply sorting of column using above method calling with `FieldName` & `Method of sorting`.

Find finalize Working Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uukjxv)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. But I want to sort table based on button click. Something like <button (click) = "sortPrice()">Low to high</button> Once I click the button I need to sort the table based on prices. Along with both ascending and descending order.

Comment: let me try will update answer

Comment: I asked chatGPT and it comes up with an answer. but I'm getting some error can you help me with this error and verify whether this may work? 
View code: 
<button (click)="priceHighToLow()"> High to low</button>
Ts code: 
priceHighToLow() {
    this.sort.active = 'price';
    this.sort.direction = 'desc';
  }
Error message: 
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'active'). Thank you for your time.

Comment: could you please check now my answer.

Comment: I was trying to implement your code and I got the same error: shopping.component.html:45 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sort') and at ShoppingComponent.orderData (shopping.component.ts:59:18)
    at ShoppingComponent_Template_button_click_37_listener (shopping.component.html:46:40)

Comment: try now. let know if not work .

Comment: Still the same error. I really thank you for the effort. I honestly have no clue how that works.

Comment: wait will create stackbliz link for you

Comment: Thank you so much I will cross check definitely. For more info, the dataSource is from a json, does it have any effects on sorting dataSource, they are not statically typed?

Comment: find finalize stackbliz demo link

Comment: Omg, thank you so much. It's working. I got stuck here for like 4 hours. Thank you so much

Comment: I have also spend more time on it. although nice question & approach for me also.

Comment: Yes, I never expected someone could solve this for me. This is a part of my training and I will try to figure out what's actually happening in the sort function.  Have a good day sir.

Comment: welcome friend, I feel that this is unique one so you can save this answer